# How to return the value of AUTO INCREMENT column in SQLite with VB6

Tags: sqlite, vb6, auto-increment

I have a table in SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE "EventType" 
(
[EventTypeID] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
[EventTypeName] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

Since EventTypeID is an integer and a primary key, that automatically makes it an auto-incrementing column, and that works fine.

I'd like to insert a row into the table and get the newly incremented value from VB6.

```
Dim oRs as Recordset
dim oCmd as new Command

oCmd.ActiveConnection = GetConnection()
oCmd.Source = "insert into EventType (EventTypeName) values ('blah')"
oCmd.Execute
```

Is there an automatic way to retrieve the newly created EventTypeID without having to issue another query (select max(EventTypeID) from EventType))?

I seem to remember from VB6 days long time ago, that there was a way to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does SQLite support SCOPE\_IDENTITY?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304543/does-sqlite-support-scope-identity)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Does SQLite support SCOPE_IDENTITY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304543/does-sqlite-support-scopeidentity)

> Check out the [FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1). The
>   [sqlite3_last_insert_rowid()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html)
>   function will do it. Careful of
>   triggers though

Not tested, but you should be able to send both statements in one call.  It's been a while since I wrote any VB6.  Also this is not SQL injection safe.

```
Dim oRs as Recordset
dim sSql as String
sSql = "INSERT INTO EventType (EventTypeName) VALUES ('blah'); SELECT last_insert_rowid() FROM EventType"
oRs.Open sSql oConn
```

Comment: btw, with the ODBC driver, you have to split your query into 2 calls.

Comment: so what does Insert() return then? - I know I can look it up but it might be useful here for completeness, since that's how I found this post.

Answer (score 13):

Run this query inside of your code:

```
SELECT SEQ from sqlite_sequence WHERE name='tablename'
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't use VB, so I don't know the interface you're using with your database, but, as bendewey said, there is a function in the c API called `sqlite3_last_insert_rowid()` that will return the primary integer key for the last inserted row, so you could look for a similar function in your interface.

If that doesn't work, you can use the SQLite-specific query:

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call `SELECT last_insert_rowid()` after your insert

Answer (score 1):

Since Version 3.35 you can use

```
Insert Into <yourtable> Default Values Returning <idcolumn>
```

Run the Insert with ExecuteScalar.

Answer (score -1):

If use

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid()
```

returns the last `rowid`, you can use :

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid() AS rowid FROM table_name LIMIT 1
```

for obtain the last `rowid` for an individual table

Comment: This not what the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid) says: "The last_insert_rowid() SQL function is a wrapper around the sqlite3_last_insert_rowid() C/C++ interface function." which means that there is no such thing as the last `rowid` for an individual table.