# How to retrieve the last autoincremented ID from a SQLite table?

Tags: database, sqlite, primary-key, auto-increment, junction-table

I have a table Messages with columns ID (primary key, autoincrement) and Content (text).
I have a table Users with columns username (primary key, text) and Hash.
A message is sent by one Sender (user) to many recipients (user) and a recipient (user) can have many messages.
I created a table Messages_Recipients with two columns: MessageID (referring to the ID column of the Messages table and Recipient (referring to the username column in the Users table). This table represents the many to many relation between recipients and messages.

So, the question I have is this. The ID of a new message will be created after it has been stored in the database. But how can I hold a reference to the MessageRow I just added in order to retrieve this new MessageID? 
 I can always search the database for the last row added of course, but that could possibly return a different row in a multithreaded environment?

EDIT: As I understand it for SQLite you can use the `SELECT last_insert_rowid()`. But how do I call this statement from ADO.Net?

My Persistence code (messages and messagesRecipients are DataTables):

```csharp
public void Persist(Message message)
{
    pm_databaseDataSet.MessagesRow messagerow;
    messagerow=messages.AddMessagesRow(message.Sender,
                            message.TimeSent.ToFileTime(),
                            message.Content,
                            message.TimeCreated.ToFileTime());
    UpdateMessages();
    var x = messagerow;//I hoped the messagerow would hold a
    //reference to the new row in the Messages table, but it does not.
    foreach (var recipient in message.Recipients)
    {
        var row = messagesRecipients.NewMessages_RecipientsRow();
        row.Recipient = recipient;
        //row.MessageID= How do I find this??
        messagesRecipients.AddMessages_RecipientsRow(row);
        UpdateMessagesRecipients();//method not shown
    } 

}

private void UpdateMessages()
{
    messagesAdapter.Update(messages);
    messagesAdapter.Fill(messages);
}
```

Comment: I use SQlite (the ADO.Net version)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531109/how-to-return-the-value-of-auto-increment-column-in-sqlite-with-vb6

Answer (score 114, accepted):

With SQL Server you'd SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() to get the last identity value for the current process.

With SQlite, it looks like for an autoincrement you would do

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid()
```

immediately after your insert.

http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg09429.html

In answer to your comment to get this value you would want to use SQL or OleDb code like:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    string sql = "SELECT last_insert_rowid()";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    conn.Open();
    int lastID = (Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: Thank you again! Unfortunately it does not work  as the last_insert_rowid() function needs to be called before the connection that is used to update the DataTable is closed. This may be a quirk of SQLite though...

Comment: Sorry, yes that's probably true.  Did you try executing it after the messagesAdapter.Update(messages);

Comment: @Dabblernl seems another answer is more reliable, you might want to change the accepted answer if you feel another one is more helpful

Comment: But RowId is not always the same as PRIMARY KEY. Except `If the table has a column of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY then that column is another alias for the rowid.`

Comment: You need to execute it in the same connection. Otherwise, it does not give the correct id.

Comment: **This answer is outdated since 2021** for the most common use case. See Dmitry's answer below using the [sqlite RETURNING clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_returning.html). From the docs, "The RETURNING clause is designed to provide the application with the values of columns that are filled in automatically by SQLite."

Answer (score 129):

One other option is to look at the system table `sqlite_sequence`. Your sqlite database will have that table automatically if you created any table with autoincrement primary key. This table is for sqlite to keep track of the autoincrement field so that it won't repeat the primary key even after you delete some rows or after some insert failed (read more about this here http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

So with this table there is the added benefit that you can find out your newly inserted item's primary key even after you inserted something else (in other tables, of course!). After making sure that your insert is successful (otherwise you will get a false number), you simply need to do:

```
select seq from sqlite_sequence where name="table_name"
```

Comment: It works when sequence is incremented and after row deletion.

Comment: Good answer. Strange that in "DB Browser for SQLite" if remove a row from "sqlite_sequence", you won't get a last id for some table anymore.

Answer (score 15):

I've had issues with using `SELECT last_insert_rowid()` in a multithreaded environment. If another thread inserts into another table that has an autoinc, last_insert_rowid will return the autoinc value from the new table.

Here's where they state that in the doco:

> If a separate thread performs a new INSERT on the same database connection while the sqlite3_last_insert_rowid() function is running and thus changes the last insert rowid, then the value returned by sqlite3_last_insert_rowid() is unpredictable and might not equal either the old or the new last insert rowid.

That's from [sqlite.org doco](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html)

Comment: I guess you could use a separate connection for each thread, but I've noticed that it has a big performance hit. I can only do about 15 inserts per second in my scenario.

Comment: My guess is that separate threads would be the same issue. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a thread-safe work around to date, my hunch is multiple transactions wouldn't even be enough...so be careful :|

Answer (score 9):

According to [Android Sqlite get last insert row id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575166/android-sqlite-get-last-insert-row-id) there is another query:

```
SELECT rowid from your_table_name order by ROWID DESC limit 1
```

Comment: This option has a performance penalty due execute a sort algorithm before finding the rowid

Comment: Maybe it is less optimal, but it actually works once the connection has been closed and reopened, and the other two solutions didn't for me.

Comment: The following variant avoids `ORDER BY`. Should be faster, but I did not test that: `SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM your_table_name`

Answer (score 6):

Sample code from @polyglot solution

```csharp
SQLiteCommand sql_cmd;
sql_cmd.CommandText = "select seq from sqlite_sequence where name='myTable'; ";
int newId = Convert.ToInt32( sql_cmd.ExecuteScalar( ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post but for further readers, below might be the simplest and most reliable way - just use the Returning clause with RowId (this is a special alias name for the numeric Primary Key in SQLite):

```
insert into MyTable (Column1, Column2) Values (Val1, Val2) Returning RowId;
```

In .Net you can just run it and return the value with `ExecuteScalar`.

Answer (score 1):

sqlite3_last_insert_rowid() is unsafe in a multithreaded environment (and documented as such on SQLite)
However the good news is that you can play with the chance, see below

ID reservation is NOT implemented in SQLite, you can also avoid PK using your own UNIQUE Primary Key if you know something always variant in your data.

Note:
See if the clause on RETURNING won't solve your issue
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_returning.html
As this is only available in recent version of SQLite and may have some overhead, consider Using the fact that it's really bad luck if you have an insertion in-between your requests to SQLite

see also if you absolutely need to fetch SQlite internal PK, can you design your own predict-able PK:
https://sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html

If need traditional PK AUTOINCREMENT, yes there is a small risk that the id you fetch may belong to another insertion. Small but unacceptable risk.

A workaround is to call twice the sqlite3_last_insert_rowid()

#1 BEFORE my Insert, then #2 AFTER my insert

as in :

```
int IdLast = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(m_db);   // Before (this id is already used)

const int rc = sqlite3_exec(m_db, sql,NULL, NULL, &m_zErrMsg);

int IdEnd = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(m_db);    // After Insertion most probably the right one,
```

In the vast majority of cases IdEnd==IdLast+1. This the "happy path" and you can rely on IdEnd as being the ID you look for.

Else you have to need to do an extra SELECT where you can use criteria based on IdLast to IdEnd (any additional criteria in WHERE clause are good to add if any)

Use `ROWID` (which is an SQlite keyword) to SELECT the id range that is relevant.

```
"SELECT my_pk_id FROM Symbols WHERE ROWID>%d && ROWID<=%d;",IdLast,IdEnd);
```

// notice the > in:  ROWID>%zd, as we already know that IdLast is NOT the one we look for.

As second call to sqlite3_last_insert_rowid is done right away after INSERT, this SELECT generally only return 2 or 3 row max.
Then search in result from SELECT for the data you Inserted to find the proper id.

Performance improvement: As the call to sqlite3_last_insert_rowid() is way faster than the INSERT, (Even if mutex may make that wrong it is statistically true) I bet on IdEnd to be the right one and unwind the SELECT results by the end. Nearly in every cases we tested the last ROW does contain the ID you look for).

Performance improvement: If you have an additional UNIQUE Key, then add it to the WHERE to get only one row.

I experimented using 3 threads doing heavy Insertions, it worked as expected, the preparation + DB handling take the vast majority of CPU cycles, then results is that the Odd of mixup ID is in the range of 1/1000 insertions (situation where IdEnd>IdLast+1)

So the penalty of an additional SELECT to resolve this is rather low.

Otherwise said the benefit to use the sqlite3_last_insert_rowid() is great in the vast majority of Insertion, and if using some care, can even safely be used in MT.

Caveat: Situation is slightly more awkward in transactional mode.

Also SQLite didn't explicitly guaranty that ID will be contiguous and growing (unless AUTOINCREMENT). (At least I didn't found information about that, but looking at the SQLite source code it preclude that)

Answer (score 0):

the simplest method would be using :

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM yourTableName LIMIT 1;
```

if you are trying to grab this last id in a relation to effect another table as for example : 
 **(** `if invoice is added THEN add the ItemsList to the invoice ID` **)**

 in this case use something like :

```
var cmd_result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // return the number of effected rows
```

then use `cmd_result` to determine if the previous Query have been excuted successfully,
 something like :
 `if(cmd_result > 0)` followed by your Query `SELECT MAX(id) FROM yourTableName LIMIT 1;` 
 just to make sure that you are not targeting the wrong row id in case the previous command did not add any Rows.

in fact `cmd_result > 0` condition is very necessary thing in case anything fail . specially if you are developing a serious Application, you don't want your users waking up finding random items added to their invoice.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came up with a solution to this problem that sacrifices some performance overhead to ensure you get the correct last inserted ID.

Let's say you have a table `people`. Add a column called `random_bigint`:

```
create table people (
    id int primary key,
    name text,
    random_bigint int not null
);
```

Add a unique index on `random_bigint`:

```
create unique index people_random_bigint_idx
ON people(random_bigint);
```

In your application, generate a random bigint whenever you insert a record. I guess there is a trivial possibility that a collision will occur, so you should handle that error.

My app is in Go and the code that generates a random bigint looks like this:

```
func RandomPositiveBigInt() (int64, error) {
    nBig, err := rand.Int(rand.Reader, big.NewInt(9223372036854775807))
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    return nBig.Int64(), nil
}
```

After you've inserted the record, query the table with a `where` filter on the random bigint value:

```
select id from people where random_bigint = <put random bigint here>
```

The unique index will add a small amount of overhead on the insertion. The id lookup, while very fast because of the index, will also add a little overhead.

However, this method will guarantee a correct last inserted ID.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is that, within one transaction, we insert data and immediately request the maximum value of the PRIMARY KEY field.

Here's my example.
**DayliForecast.sq:**

```
import kotlin.Int;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DailyForecast (
    pid             INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT DEFAULT NULL,
    year            INTEGER AS Int  NOT NULL,
    month           INTEGER AS Int  NOT NULL,
    day_of_month    INTEGER AS Int  NOT NULL,
    hours_of_sun    REAL            NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    forecast_key    TEXT            NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS DailyForecastDate ON DailyForecast (
    year            DESC,
    month           DESC,
    day_of_month    DESC,
    forecast_key    DESC
);

insert:
REPLACE INTO DailyForecast
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);

lastPid:
SELECT MAX(pid) FROM DailyForecast;

selectByDateRange:
SELECT * FROM DailyForecast
    WHERE
        forecast_key = ?
        AND year >= ?
        AND month >= ?
        AND day_of_month >= ?
        AND year <= ?
        AND month <= ?
        AND day_of_month <= ? LIMIT 5;
```

**ForecastDbRepositoryImpl:**

```
class ForecastDbRepositoryImpl(private val database: Database): ForecastDbRepository() {

    override suspend fun insertDailyForecast(dailyForecast: DailyForecast): Long {
        return database.transactionWithResult {
            insertForecast(dailyForecast)
        }
    }

    override suspend fun insertDailyForecast(dailyForecasts: List<DailyForecast>): List<Long> {
        return database.transactionWithResult {
            dailyForecasts.map { insertForecast(it) }
        }
    }

    private fun insertForecast(dailyForecast: DailyForecast): Long {
        database.dayliForecastQueries.insert(
            pid = dailyForecast.pid.takeIf { it >= 0L },
            year = dailyForecast.year,
            month = dailyForecast.month,
            day_of_month = dailyForecast.day_of_month,
            hours_of_sun = dailyForecast.hours_of_sun,
            forecast_key = dailyForecast.forecast_key
        )
        return database.dayliForecastQueries.lastPid().executeAsOne().MAX ?: 0L
    }
}
```

I just tested this myself and it works great!

Comment: Important addition. If you want auto-increment to work in this example, you need to use just such a constructor:
`REPLACE INTO DailyForecast
     VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);`

And pass null to argument named pid