# SQLite, Don't want to get max _id, I want to get the "next" _id

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Let's say I make 5 entries in a sqlite db.

```
_id | Name
1    Tom
2    Oskar
3    Matt
4    Mike
5    Ed
```

If I delete number 4 and 5, I only have 1-3. I then do a max _id query then I get number 3. But, of course I want the next auto incremented _id. What would be the method to do to get the number "6" in this example?

Comment: So why don't you make it auto-incremented. Then you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: You might want to read [this](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)  and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127138/how-to-retrieve-the-last-autoincremented-id-from-a-sqlite-table) links for your answer

Comment: It is autoincrement. But, I have a program that needs to know the next id, because when I use max id, my program is thrown off track.

Comment: If you are relying on the auto increment _id somewhere else in your code, then sorry, but your design is wrong.  The purpose of the _id field is for when you cannot, or do not need, a primary key across your columns.

Comment: I'm using it with conjunction with something else, so it's a lot more difficult than it seems.

Answer (score 5):

If your `_id` column has type [`INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), you can read the current sequence value from the [`sqlite_sequence`](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#seqtab) table, and thus determine the next one:

```sql
SELECT seq + 1 FROM main.sqlite_sequence WHERE name = 'mytablename'
```

Comment: how to run this on android cursor?

Comment: @Vivek In the same way as any other SQL query.