# SQLite relational INSERT with unknown foreign key

Tags: database, vb.net, sqlite, query-performance

I made an SQLite database in a VB.NET application. It stores time series data for multiple `varName` records over 2 tables:

1. Table `varNames` :

   ```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS varNames(
       id      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
       varName TEXT    UNIQUE
   );
   ```

   It looks like this:

   ```
   ID   |  varName
   ---------------
   1    |  var1
   2    |  var2
   ...  |  ...
   ```
2. Table `varValues` :

   ```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS varValues(
       timestamp INTEGER,
       varValue  FLOAT,
       id        INTEGER,
       FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES varNames(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
   );
   ```

   It looks like this:

   ```
   timestamp  |  varValue  |  id
   ------------------------------
   1          |  1.0345    |  1
   4          |  3.5643    |  1
   1          |  7.7866    |  2
   3          |  4.5668    |  2
   ...        |  ....      | ...
   ```

First table contains `varName` with `ID`. The second contains the values of each `varName` as time series (per `timestamp`). A foreign key links the tables. Insert into `varNames` looks like this:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO varNames (
    varName
) VALUES (
    @name
);
```

I insert values for a specific `varName` to the second table like this:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO varValues (
    timestamp,
    varValue,
    id
) VALUES (
    @timestamp,
    @value,
    (SELECT id FROM varNames WHERE varName = @name)
);
```

I don't know the `varName`'s `ID` for the corresponding `varValues` record at the time of insert. This is why I use :

```
(SELECT id FROM varNames WHERE varName = @name)
```

Seems slow compared to addressing by `ID` directly. How can I improve `INSERT` performance into the second table?

Comment: Depends on how you do things... It shouldn't be slow if you have little amount of data. You could store the value of the id in your .net code if that's possible or get the [last inserted row id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127138/how-to-retrieve-the-last-autoincremented-id-from-a-sqlite-table).

Answer (score 0):

> … improve the INSERT performance into the second table?

Use [a transaction](https://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) (preferably combine multiple `INSERT`):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT OR REPLACE INTO varValues (
    timestamp,
    varValue,
    id
) VALUES (
    @timestamp,
    @value,
    (SELECT id FROM varNames WHERE varName = @name)
);

INSERT OR REPLACE INTO varValues (
    timestamp,
    varValue,
    id
) VALUES (
    @timestamp,
    @value,
    (SELECT id FROM varNames WHERE varName = @name)
);

etc. ...

END TRANSACTION;
```

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1711631/4157124).