# how can we get the id of a row that we insert through code

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I need to retrieve the id of the row inserted just now. ie, i have a table for words and a table for meaning. i need the wordId of the word i insert in the table for words and that wordId is used for inserting the meaning in meaning table. Can anyone help me out??

I thought i could use trigger and tried the trigger:

"CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS word_insert_trigger AFTER INSERT ON tb_words BEGIN select NEW.word_id from tb_words; END;"

like this. i tried this in sqlite dbbrowser. but it didn't work out.

i need the row id when i insert a row like this :"insert into tb_words(word_name) values('test');"

How can i do that without using "SELECT last_insert_rowid()"? like in the following link:
[How to retrieve the last autoincremented ID from a SQLite table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127138/how-to-retrieve-the-last-autoincremented-id-from-a-sqlite-table)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve the last autoincremented ID from a SQLite table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127138/how-to-retrieve-the-last-autoincremented-id-from-a-sqlite-table)

Comment: Do the Android sqlite bindings not provide a wrapper for `sqlite3_last_insert_rowid()`?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I already saw that answer and Actually i wanted an answer other than that. that's why i asked this question here again

Comment: Could you explain why you want some other answer than the one that works?

Comment: Sorry actually it was a thinking mistake, i thought with that answer if we enter two words at a time we only get the last words id. But i forgot it is our local db and we can't enter two words at a time here. I shouldn't have mentioned SQLite, if we are inserting directly to server through api we can't use that answer. There the problem of two rows at a time exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a trigger. Use the SQliteDatabase [insert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String,%2520android.content.ContentValues)) method. It returns the **id** (as a **long**) (more correctly it returns the **rowid** and assuming that the **word_id** column has been defined as an alias of the **rowid** column, then the returned value will be the value assigned to the word_id column).

An alias of the **rowid** column is defined if `word_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` is coded (the AUTOINCREMENT key may be used BUT in generally should not be used).

You may wish to read [SQLite AUTOINCREMENT](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) and/or [Rowid Tables](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html)

Instead of something like :-

```
db.execsql("insert into tb_words(word_name) values('test');");
```

You would use something like :-

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("word_name","test");
long word_id = db.insert("tb_words",null,cv);
```