# How to get the ID of new row in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, generated-columns

I want to fill a column with a format using its ID.

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST" 
(
    "ID"    INTEGER,
    "Formatted_Column"  TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("ID" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

I want to do:

```
INSERT INTO TEST (Formatted_Column) VALUES ('U' + this_ID);

INSERT INTO TEST (Formatted_Column) VALUES ('U' + this_ID);
```

I want the output to be:

| ID | Formatted_Column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | U1 |
| 2 | U2 |

What methods can help me?

**Note**: I tried to use `last_insert_rowid()+1`, but I think it's kind of spaghetti code (: .

My database currently SQLite, but I will change it to MySQL or SQL Server later.

I will use an online database with multi-users.

Thank you

Comment: What is the reason to duplicate this information? Primary key should be used for identification purposes only. Databases mentioned at the end support calculated columns, but I hope you do not a calculated column

Comment: I know. I have my own scenario that requires me to duplicate The ID.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve the last autoincremented ID from a SQLite table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127138/how-to-retrieve-the-last-autoincremented-id-from-a-sqlite-table)

Comment: For SQL Server have a look at for instance this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/sql-server-best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of SQLite is 3.31.0+ you can define `Formatted_Column` as a [`generated column`:](https://www.sqlite.org/gencol.html) (`VIRTUAL` or `STORED`):

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST" (
  "ID" INTEGER,
  "Formatted_Column" TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS ('U' || ID) STORED,
  PRIMARY KEY("ID" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

After you insert 2 rows:

```
INSERT INTO TEST (ID) VALUES (NULL), (NULL);
```

you will have:

> | ID | Formatted_Column |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | U1 |
> | 2 | U2 |