# How Do I create an autoincrement field in SQL and refer back?

Tags: sql, flask

I am creating a flask backend that saves details of a DND style character on an SQL server. This is the application script for the input of the character details.

```
@app.route("/add_char", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def add_char():

    if request.method == "POST":

            cha_id = db.execute("""INSERT INTO
                character_basics (
                    char_id, user_id, name, race, cha_class, level, experience, alignment_lc, alignment_ge,
                    height, weight, handedness, eye_colour, hair_colour, sex, age, status,
                    max_hp, current_hp, strength, dexterity, constitution, intelligence,
                    wisdom, charisma, fortune
                ) VALUES (
                    :char_id, :user_id, :name, :race, :cha_class, :level, :experience, :alignment_lc, :alignment_ge,
                    :height, :weight, :handedness, :eye_colour, :hair_colour, :sex, :age, :status,
                    :max_hp, :current_hp, :strength, :dexterity, :constitution, :intelligence,
                    :wisdom, :charisma, :fortune
                )
                """,
                    user_id = session["user_id"],
                    name = request.form.get("name"),
                    race = request.form.get("race"),
                    cha_class = request.form.get("cha_class"),
                    level = request.form.get("level"),
                    experience = request.form.get("experience"),
                    alignment_lc = request.form.get("alignment_lc"),
                    alignment_ge = request.form.get("alignment_ge"),
                    height = request.form.get("height"),
                    weight = request.form.get("weight"),
                    handedness = request.form.get("handedness"),
                    eye_colour = request.form.get("eye_colour"),
                    hair_colour = request.form.get("hair_colour"),
                    sex = request.form.get("sex"),
                    age = request.form.get("age"),
                    status = request.form.get("status"),
                    max_hp = request.form.get("max_hp"),
                    current_hp = request.form.get("current_hp"),
                    strength = request.form.get("strength"),
                    dexterity = request.form.get("dexterity"),
                    constitution = request.form.get("constitution"),
                    intelligence = request.form.get("intelligence"),
                    wisdom = request.form.get("wisdom"),
                    charisma = request.form.get("charisma"),
                    fortune = request.form.get("fortune")
                )

            db.execute("""INSERT into
                char_academic (
                    cha_id, anatomy, anatomy_basic, animal_lore, animal_lore_spec,
                    appraisal, appraisal_spec, arcana, arcana_spec, botany_forestry,
                    botany_spec, engineering, engineering_spec, history, history_spec,
                    mathematics, mathematics_spec, religion, religion_spec
                ) VALUES (
                    :cha_id, :anatomy, :anatomy_spec, :animal_lore, :animal_lore_spec,
                    :appraisal, :appraisal_spec, :arcana, :arcana_spec, :botany_foresty,
                    :botany_spec, :engineering, :engineering_spec, :history, :history_spec,
                    :mathematics, :mathematics_spec, :religion, :religion_spec
                )
                """,
                    anatomy = request.form.get("anatomy"),
                    anatomy_spec = request.form.get("anatomy_spec"),
                    animal_lore = request.form.get("animal_lore"),
                    animal_lore_spec = request.form.get("animal_lore_spec"),
                    appraisal = request.form.get("appraisal"),
                    appraisal_spec = request.form.get("appraisal_spec"),
                    arcana = request.form.get("arcana"),
                    arcana_spec = request.form.get("arcana_spec"),
                    botany_forestry = request.form.get("botany_forestry"),
                    botany_spec = request.form.get("botany_spec"),
                    engineering = request.form.get("engineering"),
                    engineering_spec = request.form.get("engineering_spec"),
                    history = request.form.get("history"),
                    histroy_spec = request.form.get("history_spec"),
                    mathematics = request.form.get("mathematics"),
                    mathematics_spec = request.form.get("mathematics_spec"),
                    religion = request.form.get("religion"),
                    religion_spec = request.form.get("religion_spec")
                )

            db.execute("""INSERT into
                char_profession (
                    char_id, agriculture, agriculture_spec, blacksmithing,
                    blacksmithing_spec, commerce, commerce_spec, jeweller,
                    jeweller_spec, leather_working, leather_spec, masonry,
                    masonry_spec, metal_working, metal_working_spec, sailing,
                    sailing_spec, tailoring, tailoring_spec, woodworking,
                    woodworking_spec
                ) VALUES (
                    :char_id, :agriculture, :agriculture_spec, :blacksmithing,
                    :blacksmithing_spec, :commerce, :commerce_spec, :jeweller,
                    :jeweller_spec, :leather_working, :leather_spec, :masonry,
                    :masonry_spec, :metal_working, :metal_working_spec, :sailing,
                    :sailing_spec, :tailoring, :tailoring_spec, :woodworking,
                    :woodworking_spec
                )
                """,
                    agriculture = request.form.get("agriculture"),
                    agriculture_spec = request.form.get("agriculture_spec"),
                    blacksmithing = request.form.get("blacksmithing"),
                    blacksmithing_spec = request.form.get("blacksmithing_spec"),
                    commerce = request.form.get("commerce"),
                    commerce_spec = request.form.get("commerce_spec"),
                    jeweller = request.form.get("jeweller"),
                    jeweller_spec = request.form.get("jeweller_spec"),
                    leather_working = request.form.get("leather_working"),
                    leather_spec = request.form.get("leather_spec"),
                    masonry = request.form.get("masonry"),
                    masonry_spec = request.form.get("masonry_spec"),
                    metal_working = request.form.get("metal_working"),
                    metal_working_spec = request.form.get("metal_working_spec"),
                    sailing = request.form.get("sailing"),
                    sailing_spec = request.form.get("sailing_spec"),
                    tailoring = request.form.get("tailoring"),
                    tailoring_spec = request.form.get("tailoring_spec"),
                    woodworking = request.form.get("woodworking"),
                    woodworking_spec = request.form.get("woodworking_spec")
                )

            db.execute("""INSERT into
                cha_gen_skills (
                    cha_id, acrobatics, acrobatics_spec, culture, culture_spec,
                    dancing, dancing_spec, first_aid, first_aid_spec,
                    manual_labour, labour_spec, musical_ability, music_spec,
                    observation, observation_spec, sleight, sleight_spec,
                    sneak, sneak_spec, social_interaction, social_spec, tracking,
                    tracking_spec, upkeep_maintenance, upkeep_spec
                ) VALUES (
                    :cha_id, :acrobatics, :acrobatics_spec, :culture, :culture_spec,
                    :dancing, :dancing_spec, :first_aid, :first_aid_spec,
                    :manual_labour, :labour_spec, :musical_ability, :music_spec,
                    :observation, :observation_spec, :sleight, :sleight_spec,
                    :sneak, :sneak_spec, :social_interaction, :social_spec, :tracking,
                    :tracking_spec, :upkeep_maintenance, :upkeep_spec
                )
                """,
                    acrobatics = request.form.get("acrobatics"),
                    acrobatics_spec = request.form.get("acrobatics_spec"),
                    culture = request.form.get("culture"),
                    culture_spec = request.form.get("culture_spec"),
                    dancing = request.form.get("dancing"),
                    dancing_spec = request.form.get("dancing_spec"),
                    first_aid = request.form.get("first_aid"),
                    first_aid_spec = request.form.get("first_aid_spec"),
                    manual_labour = request.form.get("manual_labour"),
                    labour_spec = request.form.get("labour_spec"),
                    musical_ability = request.form.get("musical_ability"),
                    muscic_spec = request.form.get("music_spec"),
                    observation = request.form.get("observation"),
                    observation_spec = request.form.get("observation_spec"),
                    sleight = request.form.get("sleight"),
                    sleight_spec = request.form.get("sleight_spec"),
                    sneak = request.form.get("sneak"),
                    sneak_spec = request.form.get("sneak_spec"),
                    social_interaction = request.form.get("social_interaction"),
                    social_spec = request.form.get("social_spec"),
                    tracking = request.form.get("tracking"),
                    tracking_spec = request.form.get("tracking_spec"),
                    upkeep_maintenance = request.form.get("upkeep_maintenance"),
                    upkeep = request.form.get("upkeep_spec")
                )

            db.execute("""INSERT into
                cha_lang_skills (
                    cha_id, common, common_spec, dwarven, dwarven_spec, elvish,
                    elvish_spec, gnomeish, gnomeish_spec, halfling, halfling_spec
                ) VALUES (
                    :cha_id, :common, :common_spec, :dwarven, :dwarven_spec, :elvish,
                    :elvish_spec, :gnomeish, :gnomeish_spec, :halfling, :halfling_spec
                )
                """,
                    common = request.form.get("common"),
                    common_spec = request.form.get("common_spec"),
                    dwarven = request.form.get("dwarven"),
                    dwarven_spec = request.form.get("dwarven_spec"),
                    elvish = request.form.get("elvish"),
                    elvish_spec = request.form.get("elvish_spec"),
                    gnomeish = request.form.get("gnomeish"),
                    gnomeish_spec = request.form.get("gnomeish_spec"),
                    halfling = request.form.get("halfling_spec")
                )
```

As far as I Understand it, the first section of code creates the `cha_id` but then how do I call it back for the subsequent calls?

These are the SQL tables...

```
-- Table structure for character_basics
----
CREATE TABLE 'character_basics' ('char_id' integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 'user_id' integer NOT NULL, 'name' text NOT NULL, 'race' text NOT NULL, 'cha_class' text NOT NULL, 'level' integer NOT NULL, 'experience' integer NOT NULL, 'alignment_lc' text NOT NULL, 'alignment_ge' text NOT NULL, 'height' integer NOT NULL, 'weight' integer NOT NULL, 'handedness' text NOT NULL, 'eye_colour' text NOT NULL, 'hair_colour' text NOT NULL, 'sex' text NOT NULL, 'age' integer NOT NULL, 'status' text NOT NULL, 'max_hp' integer NOT NULL, 'current_hp' integer NOT NULL, 'strength' integer NOT NULL, 'dexterity' integer NOT NULL, 'constitution' integer NOT NULL, 'intelligence' integer NOT NULL, 'wisdom' integer NOT NULL, 'charisma' integer NOT NULL, 'fortune'  INTEGER NOT NULL  );

----
-- Table structure for char_profession
----
CREATE TABLE 'char_profession' ('char_id' integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 'agriculture' integer NOT NULL, 'agriculture_spec' text, 'blacksmithing' integer NOT NULL, 'blacksmithing_spec' text, 'commerce' integer NOT NULL, 'commerce_spec' text, 'jeweller' integer NOT NULL, 'jeweller_spec' text, 'leather_working' integer NOT NULL, 'leather_spec' text, 'masonry' integer NOT NULL, 'masonry_spec' text, 'metal_working' integer NOT NULL, 'metal_working_spec' text, 'sailing' integer NOT NULL, 'sailing_spec' text, 'tailoring' integer NOT NULL, 'tailoring_spec' text, 'woodworking'  INTEGER NOT NULL  , 'woodworking_spec' text);

----
-- Table structure for cha_gen_skills
----
CREATE TABLE 'cha_gen_skills' ('char_id' integer NOT NULL, 'acrobatics' integer NOT NULL, 'acrobatics_spec' text, 'culture' integer NOT NULL, 'culture_spec' text, 'dancing' integer NOT NULL, 'dancing_spec' text, 'first_aid' integer NOT NULL, 'first_aid_spec' text, 'manual_labour' integer NOT NULL, 'labour_spec' text, 'musical_ability' integer NOT NULL, 'music_spec' text, 'observation' integer NOT NULL, 'observation_spec' text, 'sleight' integer NOT NULL, 'sleight_spec' text, 'sneak' integer NOT NULL, 'sneak_spec' text, 'social_interaction' integer NOT NULL, 'social_spec' text, 'tracking' integer NOT NULL, 'tracking_spec' text, 'upkeep_maintenance' integer NOT NULL, 'upkeep_spec' text);

----
-- Table structure for char_academic
----
CREATE TABLE 'char_academic' ('char_id' integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 'anatomy' integer NOT NULL, 'anatomy_spec' text, 'animal_lore' integer NOT NULL, 'animal_lore_spec' text, 'arcana' integer NOT NULL, 'arcana_spec' text, 'botany_forestry' integer NOT NULL, 'botany_spec' text, 'engineering' integer NOT NULL, 'engineering_spec' text, 'history' integer NOT NULL, 'history_spec' text, 'appraisal'  INTEGER NOT NULL  , 'appraisal_spec' text, 'mathematics'  INTEGER NOT NULL  , 'mathematic_spec' text, 'religion'  INTEGER NOT NULL  , 'religion_spec' text);
```

Thanks

Ed

Comment: Duplicate of [How to retrieve the last autoincremented ID from a SQLite table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127138/how-to-retrieve-the-last-autoincremented-id-from-a-sqlite-table)