# how to use scope_identity in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have issue when i use scop_identity in sqlite it showing the error like near "select": syntax error...i write query like this

```
   string txtSQLQuery = "insert into  SerpTrak_Site (SiteName) values ('" + txturl.Text +   "')select scope_identity();";
```

any wrong in this query please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite does not have a function by the name `scope_identity`

You are probably looking for 'SELECT last_insert_rowid()'

See also this question: [Does SQLite support SCOPE_IDENTITY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304543/does-sqlite-support-scope-identity)

Answer (score 0):

Missing a semicolon between the two queries.

```
string txtSQLQuery = "insert into  SerpTrak_Site (SiteName) 
 values ('" + txturl.Text +   "'); select scope_identity();";
```

Comment: Hi tahnk you for giving response ..What is the correct formate i have try without semicolon also but is showing error please help me....

Comment: -1 because SCOPE_IDENTITY() does not apply to SQLite databases.

Comment: -1 because I don't think there's a SCOPE_IDENTITY() in sqlite, but now I'm not sure.