# SQLite web-app, get row from insert?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, safari, mobile-safari

I have this code:

```
database.transaction(function(transaction) {
    transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO incomplete (todo, description, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?);', [todoInput, descriptionInput, myDate]);
});
```

But what I want to do is to get the row[]; (or more specifically row[id])  from what I just inserted.

Does the transaction method return any more values?

UPDATE:

I inserted it with variables, standard sqlite-webapp way.

```
    var todoInput = $('#todo').val();
    var descriptionInput = $('#description').val();
    var myDate = new Date();
    myDate.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + myDate.getDate() + '/' + myDate.getFullYear();

    database.transaction(function(transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO incomplete (todo, description, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?);', [todoInput, descriptionInput, myDate]);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to return the id straight after your insert.

add this `;select scope_identity()` to your query.

then you should be able to pull out the id of the inserted row and do what you want from there.

Comment: select scope_identity() is not supported with sqlite, but you might have pointed me in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841921/how-to-use-scope-identity-in-sqlite